# ¿Como obtener posicion listview, con un boton?

Tags: android, listview

tengo implementado un listview con sqlite, pero el evento setOnItemClickListener del listview no funciona, entonces quiero obtener la posicion de item, desde un ImagenView (img_btn_next_cliente) dentro de el item que infla al listview.

Este es le layout del Item

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:focusable="false">

<!-- Indicador de estado -->
<View
    android:id="@+id/indicator_appointment_status"
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#99ff00"
    android:focusable="false"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_item_cliente"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_nombre_negocio"
        style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        tools:text="Nombre del Negocio" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_cliente_nombre"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_nombre_negocio"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/text_nombre_negocio"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_nombre_negocio"
        android:focusable="false"
        tools:text="Cliente: Jorge Ramos" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_btn_next_cliente"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/text_nombre_negocio"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next_cliente" />
```

Esta es la clase adapter

```
public class ClientesCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ClientesCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_cliente, viewGroup, false);
}
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nombrecliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_cliente_nombre);
    TextView nombrelocal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre_negocio);
    ImageView btn_next= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_next_cliente);

    String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cnombre));
    String negocio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccodigo));
    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
    nombrecliente.setText(nombre + "id:"+id);
    nombrelocal.setText(negocio);
}
```

}

y este la actividad principal que es un fragment

```
public class f_clientes extends Fragment {
public static final int REQUEST_UPDATE_CLIENTE = 2;
private dbdata mDbCliente;
private ListView mClientesList;
private ClientesCursorAdapter mClienteAdapter;
private FloatingActionButton mAddCliente;
public f_clientes() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static f_clientes newInstance() {
   return new f_clientes();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_clientes, container, false);

    mClientesList=(ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.cliente_list);
    mClienteAdapter=new ClientesCursorAdapter(getActivity(),null);
    mClientesList.setAdapter(mClienteAdapter);
    mDbCliente=new dbdata(getActivity());
    loadClientes();
    mClientesList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l){
            Cursor currentItem = (Cursor) mClienteAdapter.getItem(i);
            System.out.println("selected value >> >> >> >> >> >>"+currentItem);
        }
    });
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) root.findViewById(R.id.fab_btn_add_Cliente);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ClienteDetalleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clienteid", "1");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return root;
}

private void loadClientes()
{
    Log.i("MClientes", "cargando clientes...");
   new ClientesLoadTask().execute();
}
private void showDetailScreen(String lawyerId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ClienteDetalleActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_ClIENTE_ID, lawyerId);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_UPDATE_CLIENTE);
}
private void showSuccessMessage(String mensaje) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
            mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
private class ClientesLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        return mDbCliente.getAllClientes();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            mClienteAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        } else {
            // Mostrar empty state
        }
    }

}
```

}

Como les comentaba, el evento setOnItemClickListener del listview no funciona, entonces quiero hacerlo de esta manera.

Comment: probaste view.setOnClickListener dentro de tu bindView?

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta, puedes ayudarme con algo más detallado

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView nombrecliente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_cliente_nombre);
    TextView nombrelocal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_nombre_negocio);
    ImageView btn_next= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_next_cliente);
    View mView =(View) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator_status);
    String nombre = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cnombre));
    String negocio = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Ccodigo));
    idC = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(contracts.clienterEntry.Cid));
    long idlng=cursor.getLong(0);
    int_id=Integer.parseInt(idC);
    int_id=int_id-6;
    idC=""+idlng;
    nombrecliente.setText(nombre + "id:  "+idC);
    nombrelocal.setText(negocio);
    mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    btn_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("in view", "onClick id :"+idC);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ClienteDetalleActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("clienteid", idC);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Al tomar el id, me devuelve con 6 mas de si posicion, es decir si id es 1 me devuelve6, pero si le resto 6, me devuelve negativos correctos, -5 -4 -3 dependiendo si la id es 1 2 3.